# SQL Profiler identify exception

Tags: sql-server-profiler

I am new to using SQL Profiler and have been using it to try and identify the source of an exception. It occurs during a trigger but does not appear to be caused by it. I have the Exception EventClass selected but I do not see any information as to where the exception was thrown from.

The exception occurs after a SELECT in the trigger that works successfully. I have inserted a RAISERROR after the select to log the parameters and return values from the select. They are all valid.

As I put more RAISERROR statements in, the exception moves further down within the trace.
I must be missing something in how to log the Exception in the profiler. I just cannot see where the exception is coming from so I can get to it and fix it.

The text of the exception is "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Needed more events to properly encapsulate the exception in Profiler.